# Preventing the bottom line from moving to the bottom line when pressing enter in Ngx-editor

Tags: ngx-editor

I'm making a chat application. And when I click enter, a new paragraph appears.
I don't want ngx-editor to create a line down when I press enter.

When I pressed the Enter key, I made the event preventDefault. And I tried with the properties of the editor, but I couldn't find it somehow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.